# Is there an existing tool to reverse engineer Xamarin AOTDATA files?

Tags: disassembly, tools, ios, .net

I am currently examining a xamarin application. It has used the "ahead of time compilation" feature, which has left some of the associated .net assemblies (.dlls) as lists of function signatures without their implementations.

It is my understanding that the implementation data is stored in the AOTDATA files. However, the files appear to have no useful strings to work off of.

How can I match the functions in the .net assemblies to the data in the AOTDATA files? How can I reverse engineer useable code out of the AOTDATA files?

It is my hope that there is an existing tool which is capable of it, but I cannot dig up anything about the structure of the files so far.